# What are the differences between Datomic and EventStoreDB?

Tags: database, datomic, eventstoredb

I am currently working on a research project that requires us to keep history of the data to access it later on. Event sourcing, naturally, falls exactly into the category of data management patterns because it allows us to replay certain events in specific points in time. Kafka or RabbitMQ probably could do this job, but they do not exactly fit our needs. So I came across [EventStoreDB](https://www.eventstore.com/), a more lightweight solution to event sourcing.

While diving deeper into database models that keep change history, I also stumbled across [this video](https://youtu.be/9TYfcyvSpEQ) of Rich Hickey who created [Datomic](https://www.datomic.com/). The concept behind Datomic sounds quite interesting and now I want to know what the difference between those two databases is. It would be great to hear some insights from people who worked with both technologies or know more about them.

Answer (score 3):

The underlying data model is quite different.

Datomic :
Datoms are the core of datomic : describing the value change of a certain attribute of the entity.

EventStoreDB:
Streams & events,
Streams represent the history of entities .
Events are tuples of (type, data , metatdata)

Both have strong total ordering guarantess.

Comment: In fact, EventStoreDB promotes using business events, and we consider property-change events (aka property sourcing) as an anti-pattern.